# How do you set filenames using Python's requests when uploading files to Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I'm using the Django Rest Framework.

If I have a simple Django model:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    file_field_1 = models.FileField(...)
    file_field_2 = models.FileField(...)
```

And a simple serializer:

```py
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

I can upload files to this API endpoint using Python's `requests` like this:

```py
requests.post(
    URL,
    files={
        "file_field_1": pathlib.Path("some_file.txt").read_bytes(),
        "file_field_2": pathlib.Path("some_other_file.txt").read_bytes(),
    },
    headers={
        "Authorization": "Token {MY_TOKEN}",
    }
)
```

This works, but the filenames that Django saves are `file_field_1` and `file_field_2`.

I think there might be a way have `requests` tell Django what each file's filename should be using the `Content-Disposition` header, but I can't seem to get it working.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can use a tuple, where the first element is the filename, and the second element is the data:

```py
requests.post(
    URL,
    files={
        "file_field_1": ("my_first_file.txt", pathlib.Path("some_file.txt").read_bytes()),
        "file_field_2": ("my_second_file.txt", pathlib.Path("some_other_file.txt").read_bytes()),
    },
    headers={
        "Authorization": "Token {MY_TOKEN}",
    }
)
```

I think this automatically causes `requests` to set the headers properly to tell Django what each filename should be.